# Directory listing behind a reverse proxy in apache

Tags: apache, webserver

I am trying to run a directory listing through a reverse proxy in apache.  Current OS is Ubuntu.  My issue is I can get to my directory listing just fine but opening any listed folder throws a 404.  Here is my current configuration

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost on
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /opendir http://192.168.1.7
ProxyPassReverse /opendir http://192.168.1.7
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
```

So an example of what's happening.  If I got to **www.myserver.com/opendir** I see the folders as expected.  If I click on one of the folders it redirects me to **www.myserver.com/folder_name** and throws a 404.  Not sure how to over come this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a / to the directory names solved my issue

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost on
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /opendir/ http://192.168.1.7/
ProxyPassReverse /opendir/ http://192.168.1.7/
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
```